# Calculate summary statistics on histogram-like data in R

Tags: r

My data is in the form of count/histogram data, ie a list of vectors, where each vector has "value" and then "count":

```
[[1]]
[1]  1 34

[[2]]
[1]      2 233799

[[3]]
[1]     3 28129

[[4]]
[1]     4 42549

[[5]]
[1]     5 52264
```

This means, for example, that a score of 1 happened 34 times, a score of 2 happened 233799 times etc.

Now, I want to be able to calculate arbitrary summary statistics on this data, like `mean`, `median`, `sd` etc. However, with the current format of the data that isn't possible. I would like to know if there is a function, datatype, or package for handling this kind of data, that would allow me to apply common statistics to this data.

My current hacky workaround is to duplicate the first number `n` times, where `n` is the count:

```
  flatten_dbl(purrr::map(data, function(datum) {
    # If the histogram has the coordinate 10, 20 it means we have seen the
    # number 10, 20 times, so we duplicate 10, 20 times
    rep(datum[[1]], datum[[2]])
  }))
```

While this works, and returns me a single vector that I can apply statistics to, it's extremely slow and memory intensive because the vector ends up with millions of values. I would like a solution that doesn't require this.

Comment: You'll not be able to calculate all the statistics with only the count data. You can get the original vector back without using `map` though. `mat <- do.call(rbind, data);rep(mat[, 1], mat[, 2])`

Comment: But it should be possible to do so, right? The mean of a count data is just the sum of column a * column b, divided by the sum of column b. Standard deviation can be calculated in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find an existing core library or CRAN package to solve this problem, so I developed `HistDat`, which is available on CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/package=HistDat